# Why was my question closed?

Tags: support, close-reasons

Can somebody please explain why my question was closed?

[How to disable PIN on SIM card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143115/how-to-disable-pin-on-sim-card)

At first I've thought that it might be because asking for workarounds may not be allowed on askubuntu as suggested in http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5305/should-questions-seeking-workarounds-for-bugs-allowed (which by the way I think is a poorly documented policy).

However since that cannot be the case as my question asks for the removal of the PIN prompt by *any* means and not only by the means of storing the PIN within the NM.

There is a fixed bug about NM which asks for a PIN being prompted despite it being stored reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/704123). That bug is very specific about removing the prompt. My question was about removing the PIN altogether, although removing the prompt would be acceptable.

However there is no bug report about being able to remote the PIN from the SIM card entirely, which was part of my question. And if there was a bug then what package would that even be. It is, if anything a missing feature...

Hence I am really puzzled on what rule I may have broken so that the my question was closed.

Was it a mistake on behalf of the mods, or is there something else that I have overlooked and should watch out for in future?

### Update

I have edited the question now in order to avoid further confusion about "Preventing the PIN prompt in Ubuntu" against "Removing the PIN on the SIM Card using Ubuntu". The question is really about the latter, while the former would also solve my problem but that is covered by the bug report.

Comment: BTW it is closed by community members having 3k+ reputation,not by mods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That questions was closed because it appears to askiing workaround for a bug, Now the question looks better after the edit

I voted for reopen

## Update

question is reopened,

Comment: Okay, thanks for that... so it was down to a simple miss-understanding of my question... I guess I'll have to be more careful with my wording then.

Answer (score -1):

Simply, because we can't fix it.
If there was a workaround I would expect to see it in the bug report.

Bugs need to be posted on Launchpad, and If you find a Bug that has allready been posted there, Click on the " This bug affects ## people. Does this bug affect you?" link.

Comment: Hey thanks for trying to answer my question. But can you please read my posts again. You got the point that it question is not a bug report. You missed the point that it is not a pure request for workaround... Or why do you think it is a pure request for a workaround?

Comment: If it was not a bug, then why did you reference a bug report?

Comment: Did you see this question, http://askubuntu.com/questions/209590/how-to-disable-popup-sim-pin-unlock-required

Comment: it was the user takkat, not me, that referenced it first. It is somewhat related, but not fully... takkat thought I was reporting a bug, which is certainly not true. But thanks for the link for the other question. Didn't see it, and its much newer. Also its for a newer Ubuntu... But might be useful.

Comment: This looks similar, It looks like if even not a bug it still might be a duplicate, http://askubuntu.com/questions/19422/pin-request-at-each-login-after-update-to-maverick/85984#85984

Comment: Okay I have edited the question. I hope now people won't miss-understand it again anymore...

Comment: Good luck on the problem, people have a hair trigger when they see anything "bug".