# Can we reopen this "bug report" that isn't being fixed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I found [a question](https://askubuntu.com/q/129671/53881) relating to an issue I'm still having with my power manager in xubuntu 12.04. One of the comments hinted on how to work around the problem, but the question had been closed. The reason given: it "should be filed as a bug report". A bug report was apparently filed, it's gone nowhere in over a year and I'm having the problem now. Can we reopen this "bug report" that doesn't seem to be getting a fix?

Comment: You should really encourage people to instead put the workarounds on the actual bug report itself!

Comment: Still though, I can see how that can be high barrier for people, so I'll vote to reopen; do make sure that the posted answers reference the bug report so users have a way to finding it.

Comment: -1 This has been [asked and answered already](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5305/12864). Questions seeking workarounds should be closed.

Answer (score 4):

We are not in a position to handle bug reports (or fix bugs), so your best action would be to help "that bug" get on its way.

I take it you want that question reopened - talking about how annoying the bug is makes no sense here. Maybe try to make a question about finding a workaround for a certain/unfixed bug.

Comment: The question title has been rephrased to ask about workarounds.